# Preventing Google Password Manager from Displaying Autofilled Password as Plain Text in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, password-manager

While creating simple page in Blazor I encountered an issue - after using Google Password Manager in Chrome to generate suggested password in registration form it correctly fills both password inputs. However, after unclicking input - with password confirmation, generated password appears as a plain text without any possibility to hide it. To cause this, user must be logged into Google Account.

My registration page:

```
@page "/"
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password-input">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password">
    </div>
</form>
```

After unclicking Confirm password input:
[After unclicking Confirm password input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSwy7.png)

Moreover, I have visited a few websites with registration forms on which I tried doing the same thing as with my page and the result was the same. I was expecting that both inputs with the password would stay the same due to security reasons but I see that is not the case. Is there any workaround to fix this problem?